# Run commands on multiple SSH servers behind a gateway/jumpserver

Tags: python, ssh, network-programming, paramiko

I'm trying to run multiple SSH sessions after connecting to the jump server. But after the 10th IP, I get a time-out error. Do I need to restart the SSH session? It won't go past 2.44.12.13 ip.

```
import socket

import paramiko
from jumpssh import SSHSession

#connect to jump server
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
gatewaysess = 
    SSHSession(host="105.111.156.15",username="user",password="Test").open()
print(gatewaysess.is_active())

list = ["8.40.12.11", "9.40.12.11", "9.40.12.18", "10.42.12.24", 
        "7.40.12.11", "5.40.12.9", "6.40.12.8", 
        "8.42.12.1", "7.42.12.8", "2.44.12.13", "1.44.12.38", "8.44.12.35",
        "2.40.12.99", "2.40.12.19", "3.40.12.20"]

for i in list:
    if i == "2.44.12.13":
        remoteses.close()
        remoteses.open()
        remoteses = gatewaysess.get_remote_session(
            i, username="user", password="test", look_for_keys=False)
        remoteses.is_active())
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable (although not the most efficient) would be to move the gateway connection into the loop.

Something like this (untested):

```
list = ["8.40.12.11", "9.40.12.11","9.40.12.18","10.42.12.24", 
        "7.40.12.11","5.40.12.9","6.40.12.8", 
        "8.42.12.1","7.42.12.8","2.44.12.13","1.44.12.38","8.44.12.35","2.40.12.99",
        "2.40.12.19","3.40.12.20"]

for i in list:
    with SSHSession(host="105.111.156.15",username="user",password="Test") as gatewaysess:
        gatewaysess.open()
        print(gatewaysess.is_active())
        with gatewaysess.get_remote_session(i, username="user", password="test", look_for_keys=False) as remoteses:
            print(remoteses.is_active())
```